# Border left and right with Neon style css

Tags: html, css, sass, pug

## Approach

I have a code that is divided into a left and right edge with the following style :

[image: Normal Border]

I would like to convert the edge by adding a neon effect like the following: 
(*I remember it's a montage with paint*) :

[image: Prototype of my thing]

## Problem

I've tried but I've obtained (*the most similar version*) :

[image: Similary version]

## Question

> Does anyone have ideas or ideas of how a similar or identical effect could be achieved?

*Thanks !!*

### Code

```css
#DivNormal {
    border-radius: 15px;
    border-right: 5px solid #8f0005;
    border-left: 5px solid #8f0005;
    align-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    text-align:center;
    margin: 0.5em !important;
    padding: 0.5em !important;
}
#DivNeon {
    border-radius: 15px;
    border-right: 5px solid #8f0005;
    border-left: 5px solid #8f0005;
    align-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    text-align:center;
    margin: 0.5em !important;
    padding: 0.5em !important;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 2px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7), 0px 0px 0px 5px red, 0px 0px 0px 3px red inset, 0px 0px 60px rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5), 0px 0px 60px rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5) inset;
 
}
```

```html
<div id="DivNormal">Hello World !!</div>
<hr>
<div id="DivNeon">Hello World !!</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's probably impossible to solve this problem by styling the element only. So, if you don't need the `::before` and `::after` pseudo-elements, you can use their borders too, to give a neon effect. This is what I came up with:

```css
#normal {
    border-radius: 15px;
    border-right: 5px solid #8f0005;
    border-left: 5px solid #8f0005;
    align-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0.5em !important;
    padding: 0.5em !important;
}

#neon {
    position: relative;
    border-radius: 15px;
    border-right: 5px solid #8f0005;
    border-left: 5px solid #8f0005;
    align-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 5.5em !important;
    padding: 0.5em !important;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 60px rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5), 0px 0px 60px rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5) inset;
}

#neon::before {
    top: 0;
    left: -9px;
    bottom: 0;
    right: -9px;
}

#neon::after {
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
}

#neon::after,
#neon::before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    border-radius: 15px;
 
    border-right: 4px solid red;
    border-left: 4px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div id="normal">Hello World !!</div>
<hr>
<div id="neon">Hello World !!</div>
```

I've increased the margin around the neon `div` just to make it easier to see, it is cleary optional. If you don't like how it looks, you can still try to adjust the position and border size values.

By the way, you shouldn't put a space before an excamation mark

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```css
#DivNormal {
    border-radius: 15px;
    border-right: 6px solid #8f0005;
    border-left: 6px solid #8f0005;
    align-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    text-align:center;
    margin: 0.5em !important;
    padding: 0.5em !important;
}
#DivNeon{
    position:relative;
    padding:15px;
    border:5px solid red;
    border-radius:20px;
    border-top:0px solid red;
    border-bottom:0px solid red;
    text-align:center;
    background:#FFB8B8;
}
#DivNeon:before {
    content:"";
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    z-index:1;
    top:2px; 
    left:5px;
    right:5px; 
    bottom:2px;
    border-radius:20px;
    border-right:6px solid red;
    border-left:6px solid red;
}
#DivNeon:after {
    content:"";
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    z-index:1;
    top:2px; 
    left:2px;
    right:2px; 
    bottom:2px;
    border-radius:20px;
    border-right:6px solid #8F0005;
    border-left:6px solid #8F0005;
}
```

```html
<div id="DivNormal">Hello World !!</div>
<hr>
<div id="DivNeon">Hello World !!</div>
```